# Change default min-width for "Request Desktop Site" function in mobile Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, viewport, blink

I have a website: 
https://montenegro-travel.info/

It's Mobile First. Desktop version starts from 1200px.

Google Chrome for Android have build-in function "Request Desktop Site". After user click it's add something like:

```
@viewport {
    min-width: 980px;
}
```

Cite from docs:

> Ignore viewport meta tags when Request Desktop Site is enabled.
>
> This matches desktop Chrome, and it applies the default "min-width:
>   980px;" in viewportAndroid.css -- putting responsive pages into their
>   desktop/tablet layout.

More details: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/5252baa9fbff3f1ffda51a4390cdf43070af22d7

This is part of Chrome:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/5d56696ce6d7399eec7ae7116fe67a0752e39004/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/viewportAndroid.css

But I want to show my users real desktop site, so searching for a native way to change 980px to 1200px.

P.S. I know how to make custom switcher for mobile|desktop version. This question about build-in Chrome feature.

Comment: This question is unclear. If you want the Chrome feature to work differently, you need to file a bug report with Chrome requesting specifically what you want to change, or join the dev team and make the change yourself. But "request desktop site" _does_ show you the "real desktop site". So it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Did you test "request desktop site" function in mobile Chrome? It shows you webstite with screan width 980px.

On most responsive websites I'm using 980px is tablet. Desktop version starts from 1200px or something like that.

I asked maybe it's possible somehow redefine this 980px to 1200px on webmaster side? Without changes in Chrome.